# Craft Commerce - Free Shipping Field

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

So there is this field called «Free Shipping» for each product.

[image]

But I can't find anything about this in the docs. I found out that I trigger it with

> product.freeShipping

But when activated it has no effect on shipping costs whatsoever.

What's the idea behind this thing, and how do I activate it?
(I'm fiddling around in the standard templates)?

I thought about creating a Free Shipping Category and then activate it via conditional. Or what's the idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free shipping flag on individual products stops costs being calculated by any shipping rule that is a `per item rate` or `weight rate`.

See https://craftcommerce.com/docs/product-model#freeshipping